# What is the correct template to override for a Document Library display form?

Tags: form, template

I am trying to use some custom list form templates (only for Display Forms), using the technique described in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa544142(v=office.14).aspx).

My basic technique is as follows:

- Create a blank .aspx page (no code-behind)
- Copy the page directives from
  `\15\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\DefaultTemplates.aspx`
- Copy the template I want to customize from `DefaultTemplates.aspx`
- Add my customizations, and rename the `id` of the template to my
  custom name
- Reference my custom template name in the `Template` attribute of the
  Display Form form element in my list definition Schema.xml, like:

`<Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" Template="MyCustomForm" WebPartZoneID="Main" />`

- Deploy my list definition and deploy my custom form template .aspx
  file to the root of the `CONTROLTEMPLATES` directory.

This works as expected if I copy and try to use a custom `ListForm` template for a regular list.

However, it seems that Document Libraries don't use the `ListForm` template, they use the `DocumentLibraryForm` template, which in turn references the `DocumentLibraryFormCore` template.

I tried using the above technique to create a custom `DocumentLibraryForm`, and kept the reference to the default `DocumentLibraryFormCore` template, as all of my customization could be contained in the outer template.  However, SharePoint never seems to load my custom template.  I have double, triple, quadruple checked that there is not a typo between the `id` that I am setting in the template file and what I reference in the `Template` element in my list definition Schema.xml.

I have even tried cutomizing both the `DocumentLibraryForm` and the `DocumentLibraryFormCore` templates, and referencing my custom `Core` form from my custom `DocumentLibraryForm`, and still nothing.

I have also searched for "DocumentLibraryForm" within the DefaultTemplates.aspx file to see if there is another template that calls the `DocumentLibraryForm` template, and is really the "outer" template I should be customizing, but there is none.

Why is SharePoint ignoring my custom form template?

Is there another template in a different file that I need to be overriding/customizing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.

The issue was that for the custom list where I used a custom `ListForm` successfully, I was using a simple custom content type and in my content type definition had `Inherits="FALSE"`, which caused the content type to defer to the form template specified in the list schema.

In the document library, I was using a custom content type that inherited from Document, and had `Inherits="TRUE"` in the definition, because Document is not the simplest content type and I didn't feel like re-constructing the whole thing just to add one custom column.

However, that meant that even if I specified my own `XmlDocuments` section in the content type definition to specify a custom form template, that would ultimately be ignored and replaced with the default document form templates, because `Inherits="TRUE"` causes that behavior. So my content type would end up with an `XmlDocuments` section calling for the default `DocumentLibraryForm` template for all forms, which would be used preferentially over the form template specified in the list schema.

So the answer was to add a feature receiver to go in and programmatically change the [`SPContentType.DisplayForTemplateName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttype.displayformtemplatename.aspx) property of my custom document content type to be my custom display template name, *after* the content type had been deployed to the site and had already been given the default form templates.